# qmake: detect target bit-width (32-bit or 64-bit)

Tags: c++, qt, architecture, qt5, qmake

I have settings in my program that depend on the bit-width of the **target** of my compilation. In case the width is 32-bit, some special macro has to be defined due to memory constraints.

I [could not find any way in qmake](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html) to detect the bit-width of the target, while the same option is available in cmake with: [`CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P.html); where 8 is 64-bit and 4 is 32-bit.

Is there something similar for qmake?

---

**EDIT:** Background on the problem as requested in the comments

**Part 1**: There's a C library that I'm using in my C++11 program that needs a macro to act differently on 32-bit systems.

**Part 2:** In 32-bit systems, the memory is limited to 4 GB of [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). Even if you're running a 64-bit system and machine, and even if you have 500 GB of swap memory, a 32-bit program cannot use more than 4 GB. That's why, the library I'm using has special settings for 32-bit as to limit the amount of memory it uses. Hence, I need to know whether we're compiling for a 32-bit target (e.g., Raspberry Pi), to activate a required macro.

**Part 3:** The library is built [as a custom target in qmake](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-custom-targets) before building my software. Once the library is built, my software is built and is linked to that library.

Comment: Correlation doesn't mean causation... Just because a `void*` happens to be `4` or `8` doesn't mean you're on a 32 or 64 bit system. It's *usually* like that, but it's not specified or standardized anywhere.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm not looking for whether it's a 32 or 64-bit *system*. I'm looking to whether *the target* is 32 or 64-bit. This is a problem related to virtual memory, which is limited to 4 GB in 32-bit targets.

Comment: Host or target doesn't matter, you still can't use the width of a pointer other than a *hint* for guessing.

Comment: Why do even need qmake or macros for this? Just make a regular `if` or `if constexpr` or template with default parameter `<bool x_32_bit = (4 == sizeof(void *))>`

Comment: Maybe `contains(QMAKE_TARGET.arch, x86_64)` qmake statement will give you the right answer?

Comment: @VTT The library that needs the macro is a C library. I'm not sure I can define macros in constexpr in my C++11 that uses the library, but that's a nice idea to try out.

Comment: @vahancho That's only for windows. Doesn't work on Linux. I tried that already.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You can compile 32-bit programs on 64-bit machines, and even run them. I don't know what you mean by hint for guessing, but memory pointers have to be aligned with the bit-width of the target arch. Can you provide an example of a 32-bit target that has 64-bit pointers or the opposite?

Comment: I'm sorry to sound rude, but if you need to tell us important details in comments, then you haven't written a good question. Please include details such as host and target platform, what you have tried, and what happened when you tried that, etc. The more details you provide in your question the less we have to ask here in comments.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No you're not rude. Don't worry about it. I thought I was clear enough in my question, since I thought the virtual-memory information and its relation to pointer size is known to everyone. I'll add this information to my question, and I just hope I won't sound pedagogical and this is why I hate this part, since I'm sure that most of you guys know way more than me.

Comment: I do know of old historical hybrid systems, for example the 16/32 bit MC68000. And in the early days of the mini-computers  there was an even bigger disconnect between "word-size" and the amount of addressable memory. These days it might be possible to find something similar in the "big-iron" systems. Now, what are you *really* trying to figure out? The "word" bit-width? The amount of addressable memory (and remember even 32-bit x86 systems can use more than 32 bits for virtual memory)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I edited the question. I hope that answers your question. I need to know the amount of addressable memory basically, and if my understanding is correct, then 32-bit systems are limited to 4 GB Virtual Memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using this solution. First I added this to support linux:

```
linux-g++:QMAKE_TARGET.arch = $$QMAKE_HOST.arch
linux-g++-32:QMAKE_TARGET.arch = x86
linux-g++-64:QMAKE_TARGET.arch = x86_64
```

and then this:

```
contains(QMAKE_TARGET.arch, x86_64) {
    message("Compiling for a 64-bit system")
} else {
    DEFINES += ABC
    message("Compiling for a 32-bit system")
}
```

Learned this from [here](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/57402-How-to-determine-target-architecture-in-qmake-project-file).

Answer (score 0):

you can add to the .pro file something like

```
*-64
{
    message( "Building for 64 bit machine...")
}
```

so when qmake is executed, you should see the msg

> Building for 64 bit machine...

Comment: I can't say this didn't occur to me... it's just tooooo generic that I'm afraid it might cover unwanted cases... don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a macro in conjunction with compile-time constants (but not preprocessor constants) to set things up:

```
#define TARGET_64 (sizeof(void*) == 8)
#define TARGET_32 (sizeof(void*) == 4)
```

Then, for example to change the amount of memory allocated:

```
char buffer1[TARGET_32 ? 0x10000000 : 0x40000000];
char *buffer2;

void foo(void) {
  buffer2 = malloc(TARGET_32 ? 0x10000000 : 0x40000000);
}
```

There's probably no need for a macro to be tested with `#ifdef` - if you think that there is, you'd need to show the subject code in your question.

Comment: I need to make a global `#define ABC` if it's 32-bit. The definition has to be done in the makefile because the library needs to be built as part of my build system. If this doesn't answer your question, please explain what information you need.

Comment: Well, the only consumer for the define is the library code, presumably in C or C++, so how do you consume that define that precludes the solution above?

Comment: My qmake file builds the library as a target, then links the library outcome to my program after building it. I don't see how this can be done with the code you provided. If it can, please explain how.

Comment: I added more information in the question on how it looks in qmake as a custom target.